# Principal value integral of $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ if f is continuous in [-1,1]

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-principal-value

Suppose $f : [-1,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, show p.v. $\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{f(x)}{x}dx$ exists.

I know that since $f(x)$ is continuous on the closed bounded interval $[1,1]$, f is then Riemann integrable on $[-1,1]$. Also since $\frac{1}{x}$ is continuous on $[-1,-\epsilon]\cup[\epsilon,1]$, so I'm guessing that $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ is continuous on the interval $[-1,1]$ except $0$. Given the definition of the principal value integral, I am not sure of how to use it and I am wondering whether I am heading in the right direction, or if I am, how I can phrase it rigourously.

Another thing I tried doing was integration by parts by the p.v. definition but it got me nowhere, please help I'm stuck.

Appreciate any kind of help, thank you.

Comment: This is interesting. Continuity of $f$ rules out nastiness that can occur with things like  $f(x)=\operatorname{sgn}(x)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**: You need to work with continuity of $f$ at $0$. Given $\eta>0$, there is $\epsilon_0>0$ so that for $|x|<\epsilon_0$ we have $|f(x)-f(0)|<\eta$. This means that $f(0)-\eta<f(x)<f(0)+\eta$ for $-\epsilon_0<x<\epsilon_0$. Now work with $\int_{-1}^{-\epsilon} + \int_\epsilon^1$ for $\epsilon<\epsilon_0$.

Comment: Do I split the integral further into $\int_{-1}^{-\epsilon_0}$ and $\int_{-\epsilon_0}^{-\epsilon}$ ? and likewise for the other side ? Furthermore, with f being continuous at 0, is your idea being substituting $f(x)$ with $f(0)$ when the integral is near $0$ ?

Comment: Yes, to both. To be rigorous, you keep the $\eta$ to estimate error, but it's as small as you want.

Comment: But then how do I evaluate the integral of $\int_{-1}^{-\epsilon_0}$ likewise for the other side, its not like I can use any integration technique to deal with it. Any hints ?

Comment: Those are just two constants. You're not trying to compute the p.v. without knowing what $f$ is; you're just trying to prove that it exists.

Comment: Ah, so basically all I have to deal with is the integral $\int_{-\epsilon_0}^{-\epsilon}$ and likewise for the other side, since the integral of $\int_{-1}^{-\epsilon}$ and $\int_{\epsilon}^{1}$ are just constants ? But the reason for being constant is that both are continuous in the interval and Riemann integrable ?

Comment: Correct: The Riemann integrals exist because you are integrating a continuous function on those two closed intervals.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you very much. By the way, just out of curiosity, does the p.v integral of $\int_{-1}^{-\epsilon_0}$ and likewise for the other side the same as the Riemann integral of the function and thus exists? since there is no problematic values in the interval and perhaps make the proof a bit more rigorous ?

Comment: You cannot talk about the principal value without taking the sum symmetrically around the origin (and taking the limit).

Comment: So principal value only works for a symmetrical interval around the origin (by taking limit) ?

Answer (score 0):

It is kinda weird but, if you look at 1/X on [-b,-a] u [a,b] (having symetrical intervals is important there), it does have an integral equal to 0 (primitives are easy there) and the limit when a->0 can then give a sense to your integral i believe

Comment: This is irrelevant, I think. Note that $f$ need not be even, so the integral would typically not be zero -- all you can say is that it exists.

Comment: yeah i agree, my point would be more like "it exists but the value of f at zero wont change the value of the integral"

Answer (score 0):

Most theorems concerning Riemann integrals have equivalent theorems concerning the corresponding improper Riemann integrals.  See pp. 266-267 of "Mathematical Analysis" (2nd ed.) by T. Apostol, for example.

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: Somebody said that you can get a lot of information about the full answer by considering the p.v. of the integral of 1/x over [-1,1], then expanding your answer from there.  I also gave a reference that is not difficult to find because this is the clearest exposition about improper integrals and principals values I have ever seen.